# how a device token is to be created for a device while using apns, what was the concept behind this

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

how a device-token is created for an app while using apns, what was the concept behind this.
Is function interact with apns server to create a device token ?

Comment: may be this will give you some idea https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: @alzert You want methods to take Token or any else ?